# Emacs into iCloud Drive for Coq

Tags: path

I use two Macs in my day to day coding studies: one iMac and one Macbook Air (three, if you count Emacs, ha ha ha). I often code on the same files with both computers, and iCloud Drive makes sense as a way to manage these files. I currently have a plain old folder alias set up from my iCloud drive to my desktop, but I can't Ctrl-X Ctrl-F my way into the iCloud Drive.

I use Emacs to work with Coq Proof Assistant, which requires Coq Proof General, Coq / Coqtop, and a bunch of installation. I want to open .v files, which I can already normally do.

Current problem: So I can access desired folder through iTerm and terminal, but navigating to that folder (~/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Documents/fpp) and then typing in `emacs Assignment 5.v` gives me this error:

`Failed to initialize color list unarchiver: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4864 "*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver _initForReadingFromData:error:throwLegacyExceptions:]: non-keyed archive cannot be decoded by NSKeyedUnarchiver" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver _initForReadingFromData:error:throwLegacyExceptions:]: non-keyed archive cannot be decoded by NSKeyedUnarchiver}`

When I enter `sudo emacs Assignment5.v`, emacs opens up but it is completely blank (i.e empty). Do help!

Desired outcome: to be able to ctrl-x ctrl-f and open any file in emacs, with the default path being directly into my iCloud\ Drive/fpp folder. Would be nice if I could ls and `emacs Assignment5.v`.

P.S while you're here give me your best Emacs tips for better proofing!